# Refresh Media in Android Auto MediaBrowserService

Tags: android, android-auto, mediabrowserservice

I have a `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` that is hooked up to Android Auto as a music player.  Everything is peachy, `onCreate`, `onGetRoot`, and `onLoadChildren` are all called as they should be.

The problem is if the underlying music is changed (loading a new playlist, shuffling, etc) I can't figure out how to tell Android Auto that it needs to call `onLoadChildren(...)` again.   Is there a way to tell it that things have changed?  I tried calling:

```
 notifyChildrenChanged(rootId);
```

but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Loading a new playlist and shuffling seem like things that would change the queue (and therefore be things reflected through the [setQueue API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat#setQueue(java.util.List%3Candroid.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat.QueueItem%3E)) as part of your `MediaSessionCompat`, not something reflected in your `MediaBrowserServiceCompat`'s structure?